# "50 процентов (от) стоимости" Нужен ли предлог "от"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

> Минимальный размер фондов капитального ремонта в отношении многоквартирных домов, собственники помещений в которых формируют указанные фонды на специальных счетах, составляет 50 процентов (от) оценочной стоимости капитального ремонта.

Answer (score 2):

Факультативно. Оба варианта верны, мне ближе без предлога -  50 процентов  оценочной стоимости.

Правило таково: **процент чего** употребляется при выражении зависимого слова **собирательным существительным или существительным, не имеющим количественного значения:** *двадцать процентов населения*, а  **процент от чего при зависимом слове – количественном числительном**: *пять процентов от шестидесяти*.

Если в качестве зависимого слова выступает существительное, связанное с понятием количества, то употребление предлога факультативно: *три процента этой суммы / три процента от этой суммы; один процент заработной платы / один процент от заработной платы.* Слово *стоимость* связано с понятием количества, следовательно, оба варианта корректны.

Answer (score 0):

1) Предлог ОТ используется, если о**пределяется процент от суммы**:

Минимальный размер фондов капитального ремонта...составляет 50 процентов **от оценочной стоимости капитального ремонта.**

2) Если называется **количество в процентах**, то предлог ОТ не используется.

**Примеры:**

Сколько же **процентов от оборота** должен составлять рекламный бюджет?

Выяснилось, что **более 30 процентов работников** налоговых органов в регионах не имеют высшего образования.

Из словаря

ПРОЦЕНТ,

1. **Сотая доля какого-л. числа,** принимаемого за целое, за единицу (обозначается знаком %). **Десять процентов от двухсот** составляет двадцать.  Сколько составит **годовой процент от этой суммы**?
2. Количество кого-, чего-л., измеряемое в сотых долях чего-л. принятого за единицу. **Сорок процентов машин** нуждается в ремонте.